# Different text size in panels

Tags: panel

The panel on the left has small unreadable text and the panels on the right are readable. whats up with this? how do i get the left panel to be readble again. when I open a new file its normal but i cant adjust it in this file

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming Blender 2.80)
To fix the size, move your mouse cursor over the panel, which you want to change. Press CTRL and hold down the mouse wheel. Then move the cursor up and down until the size of the fonts are as you want.

Comment: Great, that worked thanks. Also works in 2.79 which is what I was using.